# Is ContentEdgeInsets broken now?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

In the past i've written a small renderer for buttons to maintain a padding property on my forms element. Lately it stopped working and while debugging i noticed it says unknown member all of a sudden (which would explain why it has no effect anymore)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EnhancedButton), typeof(EnhancedButtonRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class EnhancedButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            UpdatePadding();
        }

        private void UpdatePadding()
        {
            var element = this.Element as EnhancedButton;
            if (element != null && this.Control != null)
            {
                this.Control.ContentEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(

                    (int)element.Padding.Top,
                    (int)element.Padding.Left,
                    (int)element.Padding.Bottom,
                    (int)element.Padding.Right
                );
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(EnhancedButton.Padding))
            {
                UpdatePadding();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pcl:

```
public class EnhancedButton : Button
{
    #region Padding

    public static BindableProperty PaddingProperty = BindableProperty.Create<EnhancedButton, Thickness>(d => d.Padding, default(Thickness));

    public Thickness Padding
    {
        get { return (Thickness) GetValue(PaddingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PaddingProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion Padding
}
```

Is anyone aware of a workaround? Has the support of this property been canceled on ios side?

Xamarin.Forms is 2.1.0.6524. If i recall correctly it worked just fine a couple versions ago.

Comment: can you post your  EnhancedButton class so that i can make a project for debugging to know whats going around here

Comment: @saketkumar yeah of course.

Comment: There is no complier error i am getting for above project and its compile successfully ! , i think u need to update your pkgs.

Comment: @saketkumar i'm not getting compiler errors either - it's simply not having an effect on the rendering of the button. Does changing the padding have an effect for you?

Comment: No , doesn't change anything !

Comment: @saketkumar ok. well thanks for confirming that it's broken then - because it used to work with a previous version of XF